# "You all should have" vs. "you should have all" vs. "all of you should have"

Tags: word-usage, all-of, you-all

Which one of these three constructions is more correct:

> By now, *you all* should have received your insurance cards.
>
> By now, *all of you* should have received your insurance cards.
>
> By now, *you* should have *all* received your insurance cards.

Comment: You can also use "By now, you should *all* have received your insurance cards", but move it to the end of the verb, and it completely changes the meaning: "By now, you should have received *all* your insurance cards".  Don't you love the weird after-auxiliary/modal placement of "all"?  :-)

Comment: _All_ is a quantifier, and participates in [Quantifier-Float](http://english.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a15299%20quantifier%20float).

Comment: What @JohnLawler said.

Answer (score 2):

They are all arguably correct, but I would say the least awkward is

> By now, all of you should have received your insurance cards.

because it keeps "all of you" and "should have received" in their own elegant constructions, without adjoining words potentially causing (slight) confusion.

Comment: Also, "all of you" is better because it focuses moreso on the individual, whereas "you all" focuses more on the group as a whole (at least, for my dialect, though we use "y'all" and "all of y'all").